# Mockito RETURNS_SMART_NULLS answer weird behavior

Tags: java, mockito, method-invocation

I'm using the annotation `@Mock(answer=Answers.RETURNS_SMART_NULL)` with Mockito 1.9.5 in order to get some SmartNullPointerException when some unexpected mock calls occurs.

Unfortunately, the test pass, even without mocking at least one important call. 
*To be clear* : My point is **not** to find by myself what I'm missing but to **fail** the test **because** I didn't mock the methods. I would want to do it without using `Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(...)`

My test :

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ContextServiceImplTest {

    @Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_SMART_NULLS)
    private IAccountDAO accountDaoMock; 
    @Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_SMART_NULLS)
    private IRuleService ruleServiceMock;
    @Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_SMART_NULLS)
    private ISensorDAO sensorDAOMock;

    private ContextServiceImpl contextService;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        contextService = new ContextServiceImpl(accountDaoMock, ruleServiceMock, sensorDAOMock);
    }

    @Test
    public void fillSensor() throws Exception {
        // given
        String givenSensorId = "123"
        final EventDTO givenEvent = new EventDTO();
        givenEvent.setSensorId(givenSensorId)

        // when
        final Context context = contextService.getContext(givenEvent);

        // then (should fail and throw explicit exception

    }
```

The code to be tested :

```
public class ContextServiceImpl {
    ...

    public Context getContext(final EventDTO event) throws Exception {
        final String sMethodName = "getContext";
        final String sensorId = event.getSensorId();
        Context context = new Context();

        try {
            final Sensor sensor = sensorDAO.findById(sensorId);
            context.setSensor(sensor);
            return context;
        } catch (final NoResultException nre) {
            throw new BusinessException(ValidationCode.UNSUPPORTED_VALUE, "sensorId");
        } catch (final PersistenceException pe) {
            throw new TechnicalException(TechnicalCode.DATABASE_ACCESS_PROBLEM);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your comments / advices / explainations.

Comment: You don't have to use an `@Before` to inject your mocks; you can just use `@InjectMocks` on the field to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call a method on the `null` object `sensor` for the test to fail.

It seems like you are never using the `null` object `sensor`. 
This means you won't get any `NullPointerExceptions` (smart or not)

you could do an

```
AssertEquals(context.getSensor().someMethod(), expectedResult);
```

or just a

```
context.getSensor().someMethod();
```

to get an exception. 
**But**

```
AssertNotNull(context.getSensor());
```

won't be sufficient to get the **SmartNullPointerException**

Comment: Ok, I understand more what does not work with my expectation. But even with a call on Sensor like `AssertEquals`or `context.getSensor.toString()` I get a NullPointerException and not a smart one (so no clue that an expectation on the mock is missing....

Comment: See http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_SMART_NULLS the documentation states "If the return type is `final` then plain null is returned"

Comment: Yep, I started by that, but in my case, none of those classes seem final. For exemple `public class Sensor { ... }`

Comment: add `private ISensorDAO sensorDAOMock = (ISensorDAO.class,  RETURNS_SMART_NULLS);`

Comment: The mockito documentation suggests that you define `RETURN_SMART_
NULLS` like  `private ISensorDAO sensorDAOMock = (ISensorDAO.class,  RETURNS_SMART_NULLS);` rather than using the `answers` annotation

Comment: your answer was almost perfect (perfect for the clues on how to find the good answer at least). I edited your post to make it more precise : calling the object `context.getSensor()` is not sufficient but any method call on it will throw the `SmartNullPointerException`

Answer (score 1):

Your tests will still pass because you're not invoking anything with the result of any of those mocked calls.

[`RETURNS_SMART_NULLS`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_SMART_NULLS) only throws a `SmartNullPointerException` if you attempt to dereference something that is a `SmartNull`.  In essence, it's telling you that you're dereferencing a `null` value in a friendlier way, and you're not doing that with your current code.

First - you new up a `Context`.  Unless you're getting into the weeds of threading problems, that will never come back `null`.

Next - you're passing in a newed `EventDTO`.  For the same reasons above, that won't be `null` either.

The result of `sensor` *may* be `null`, but it doesn't matter - you're merely passing it through to the `context` without invoking any logic on it.

I'm not convinced that `RETURNS_SMART_NULLS` is going to work the best for your scenario.  I'd recommend that you remove those answers from the mock objects.  This will cause your test to fail because you haven't expected any of those interactions.